# PHP Boolean not set

Tags: php, image, upload, boolean

I'm trying to upload an image to my local server but a boolean value is not set in my code .

I include a php file to upload the file and do my checks there .
There is no error during the process but my variable is still not set.

Verification.php

```
 // Verification si une image a été sélectionné : 
    if(isset($_POST['photo']) && !empty($_POST['photo']))
    {
        // Upload l'image dans le dossier upload si tout est valide
        include_once "upload.php";
        $uploaded = true;
    }

    //$bdd->query('INSERT INTO users(pseudo,email,password,birthday) VALUES(');
    $req = $bdd->prepare('INSERT INTO users(pseudo,email,password,DateInscription,Photo) VALUES(:identifiant,:email,:password,NOW(),:photo)');

    $req->execute(array(
        'identifiant' => $_POST["pseudo"],
        'email' => $_POST["email"],
        'password' => cryptPassword($_POST["password"]),
        'photo' => isset($uploaded) == true ? $directory : "test",
    ));
```

Upload.php

```
$form_name = "photo";
$max_size = 5000000; // = 5 MO
$validExtension = array('png','gif','jpg','jpeg');
$directory = "uploads/" .$_POST["pseudo"];

// Vérification si l'image s'est bien uploadé
if(!isset($_FILES[$form_name]) OR $_FILES[$form_name]['error'] > 0 ) 
{
    $error = "codeerreur : " .$_FILES[$form_name]['error'];
    header("Location: http://localhost/serveur_web/inscription.php?error-photo=invalid_upload" .$error);exit;
}  

// Vérification si l'image est trop lourde : > 5 MO
if($_FILES[$form_name]['size'] > $max_size) header("Location: http://localhost/serveur_web/inscription.php?error-photo=invalid_size");exit;

// Verification de l'extension de l'image 
$imageExtension = substr(strrchr($_FILES[$form_name]['name'],'.'),1);
if(!in_array($imageExtension,$validExtension)) header("Location: http://localhost/serveur_web/inscription.php?error-photo=invalid_extension");exit;

// tout est ok déplacement de l'image dans le dossier 
if(!move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$form_name]['tmp_name'],$directory))
{
    header("Location: http://localhost/serveur_web/inscription.php?error-photo=move");
    exit;
}
```

This part of the code : **isset($uploaded) == true ? $directory : "test"** always return : test .

Thank you for help.

EDIT : I already have enctype definition in my html code

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post" action="verif.php?protocol=inscription" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          <fieldset>

          <div class="form-group">
                        <input class="form-control" placeholder="Pseudo" name="pseudo" type="text">
                    </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                        <input class="form-control" placeholder="E-mail" name="email" type="text">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="password" type="password" value="">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
                        <input class="form-control" placeholder="Confirm Password" name="password_confirm" type="password" value="">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
                        <input class="form-control" placeholder="Photo de profil" name="photo" type="file" value="">
          </div>



          <input class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block" type="submit" value="Inscription">


                </fieldset>
                </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have problem in this line

```
 'photo' =>isset($uploaded) == true ? $directory : "test"
```

change this line to

```
'photo' =>($uploaded === true) ? $directory : "test";
```

if $uploaded is set true then it takes $directory value and if it is set to false then it takes "test"

set $upload to false in Verification.php

```
$uploaded = false;
if(isset($_FILES['photo']) && !empty($_FILES['photo']))
{
    include_once "upload.php";
    $uploaded = true;
}
```

Comment: if it solves your problem mark it as accepted answer, this helps others who run into to same issue.

Comment: If the code presented by the OP is complete, the original is more correct and your provided code will error when a file was not uploaded. (trying to use undefined variable $uploaded)

Comment: It's not solving my issue . it keep returning 'test' on my database  just like the $uploaded bool was set to false. Forcing the boolean to be true just send a NULL value to my databse . Thanks for your answer .

Comment: have you included enctype attribute in the form tag

Comment: code is update and working fine. changes made to if(isset($_FILES['photo']) && !empty($_FILES['photo'])) condition